# Spring Boot REST API DTO method

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, dto

I am creating simple rest api using springboot.
I am modifing my  methods because I need them to be build using DTO.
Here's code:

```
private final UserService userService;
private final UserMapper userMapper;

@GetMapping
public Page<UserDto> getUserPage(@RequestParam int page,@RequestParam int size){
    return userService.getPage(PageRequest.of(page, size));
}
```

I want function to return page of userDto (as in method header). How to change return phrase to have userDto page returned instead of user page?

Comment: Do i have to modify userService class? I think theres other possibility to do that.

Comment: What does "return phrase" means?

Comment: I mean object thats being returned by function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
Page<User> pages = userService.getPage(PageRequest.of(page, size));
Page<UserDto> pagesDto = page.map(UserDto::new);
```

Comment: Please share your BookDto class.

Comment: Data
Builder
NoArgsConstructor
AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class UserDto {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
}

Comment: I did brainstorm again and found correct implementation to this solution. I have defined method in mapper interface and implemented it. This method uses second line of your code. Thanks